# Как получить первый добавленный элемент (в map), если я не знаю его ключ?

Tags: javascript, node.js, map

```js
let map = new Map()
map.set('4', 1)
map.set('2', 2)
map.set('3', 3)
```

В данном случае будет выбран элемент с ключом `4`.

Comment: а какой именно? первый по алфавиту? словари - это такие :)

Comment: @Zhihar,первый в самом мапе

Comment: не знаю как в js, но в Java это от реализации зависит и в разных реализациях сортировка внутри Map'а часто может отличаться от порядка добавления.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let map = new Map();
map.set('4', 'abc')
map.set('2', 'def')
map.set('3', 'ghi')
console.log(map.values().next().value);
```

Comment: "**Как мне получить 1 елемент,если я не знаю его имени?**"

Comment: огромное спасибо,забыл о **.next()**

Comment: `map.values().next().value` — чуть короче и логичнее

Comment: @AlexeyTen [...map][0][1] - не оптимальный вариант, но еще чуть короче

Comment: @DiD ну тут всё-таки не code golf =)

Answer (score 1):

Можно ещё через деструктуризацию:

```js
let map = new Map();
map.set('4', 1);
map.set('2', 2);
map.set('3', 3);

const [first] = map.values();
console.log(first);
```

Comment: Жаль не могу 2 галочки поставить :(

Comment: Предыдущий ответ универсальнее, так как он не требует промежуточной переменной, его можно использовать в любом выражении, этот я просто для полноты вариантов добавил)